# Proving totality when doing induction on single constructor argument

Tags: idris

We have the following type with a single constructor:

```
-- IsTwice n is inhabited if n = k + k for some k
data IsTwice : Nat -> Type where
  Twice : (k : Nat) -> IsTwice (k + k)
```

I'm trying to define a function on `IsTwice n` for any `n`, but by doing induction on the `k` argument to the `Twice` constructor, rather than the `n` argument to `IsTwice`. My problem is that I can't get Idris to accept my definition as `total`.

Here's a specific example. Let's say we have a second type:

```
data IsEven : Nat -> Type where
  IsZero : IsEven 0
  PlusTwo : (n : Nat) -> IsEven n -> IsEven (2 + n)
```

I'd like to prove that `IsTwice n` implies `IsEven n`. My intuition is: We know that any value (witness) of type `IsTwice n` is of the form `Twice k` for some `k`, so it should be enough to inductively show that

- `Twice Z : IsTwice Z` implies `IsEven Z`, and
- if `Twice k : IsTwice (k+k)` implies `IsEven (k+k)`,
  then `Twice (S k) : IsTwice ((S k) + (S k))` implies `IsEven ((S k) + (S k))`.

```
total isTwiceImpliesIsEven : IsTwice n -> IsEven n
isTwiceImpliesIsEven (Twice Z) = IsZero
isTwiceImpliesIsEven (Twice (S k))
  = let twoKIsEven = isTwiceImpliesIsEven (Twice k) in
    let result = PlusTwo (plus k k) twoKIsEven in
    rewrite sym (plusSuccRightSucc k k) in result
```

This works except for the fact that Idris is not convinced that the proof is `total`:

```
Main.isTwiceImpliesIsEven is possibly not total due to recursive path Main.isTwiceImpliesIsEven --> Main.isTwiceImpliesIsEven
```

How can I make it `total`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even so `k` is smaller than `S k`, the totality checker cannot figure out that `k + k` is smaller than `S k + S k` as it will only reduce to `S (k + S k)`. However, it can be helped with `sizeAccessible (k + k)` in `Prelude.WellFounded`. On each recursive call you provide a `LTE` proving `k + k` always gets smaller.

```
LTERightSucc : (k:Nat) -> LTE k (S k)
LTERightSucc Z = LTEZero
LTERightSucc (S k) = LTESucc $ LTERightSucc k

total
isTwiceImpliesIsEven : IsTwice n -> IsEven n
isTwiceImpliesIsEven (Twice k) with (sizeAccessible (k + k))
  isTwiceImpliesIsEven (Twice Z) | acc = IsZero
  isTwiceImpliesIsEven (Twice (S k)) | (Access rec) =
    let twoKIsEven = (isTwiceImpliesIsEven (Twice k) |
      rec _ (LTESucc $ rewrite plusCommutative k (S k) in LTERightSucc (k+k))) in
        let result = PlusTwo (plus k k) twoKIsEven in
    rewrite sym (plusSuccRightSucc k k) in result
```